# How can I hide the password entered via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

my Question is, how can i hide the entered password.

Thats what i have:

```
<script>
check = prompt('Enter Password');
if (check != 'Test') {
  alert('Access denied!');
  window.close();
} else {
  alert('Access granted!');
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: no doubt there are reusable components out there. Also: Java is not JavaScript

Comment: i think i need something like that: <input type="password">

Comment: This can't be done in JavaScript. JavaScript lacks to customize dialog boxes (Prompt, confirm, alert). You can make your own prompt with html, css, js and get the result you want.

Comment: FYI, checks like these can easily be circumvented.

Answer (score 1):

Typically it's a html text input element with type set to password.

Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_password.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes,there is an HTML input of type "password" .

it will replace each character with a symbol such as the asterisk ("*") or a dot ("•")

depending on the user agent and OS so that it cannot be read while typing.

Comment: I think you missed an important point in the question. The question is about hiding the password __when it is entered in a JS prompt dialog__, so suggesting to use a specific type of HTML input won't help in this case.

Comment: @Nima I don't think there is a way to mask the JS prompt dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment you can't customize dialog boxes with JS. And you can achieve the same result with html, css and JS.

I made a very fast and easy to understand example.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('passForm').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function login() {
  if (document.getElementById('psw').value != 'Test') {
    alert('Access denied!');
    window.close();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('passForm').style.visibility = "hidden";
    alert('Access granted!');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.popup {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id='passForm' class="popup" style="visibility: hidden">
    <h1>Login</h1>

  <label for="psw"><b>Password: </b></label>
    <input id="psw" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</div>
```

You can change the styling so it will be more like a prompt.

You can also view a demo at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tmach/pen/oNNVvev).